# Log Out on devise does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, logout

I'm setting up a blog, and I have the sign up working well with permissions set up perfectly, but I am unable to log out the user..

this is what I see in console when I log out:

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-16 14:41:07 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

This is what my application erb file looks like:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>            
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button"><%= link_to "New Post", new_post_path %></button>
        <button class="button"><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></button>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I have the stock settings on the initializers devise.rb file

```
 # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

But for some reason when I press the log out button, I don't log out.

here is my routs.rb ( added the "devise_for :users do" code to try to get it to work):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users do
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
  resources :posts do
  resources :comments
  end

  root "posts#index"

  get '/about', to: 'pages#about'

end
```

Haaalp.... thanks.

kb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the request isn't sending the `CSRF` token. Look at the 4th line of server log:

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

Put `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` in your page should work.

Comment: that's it. thanks. I was missing that tag in my applications erb file.

Answer (score 0):

in your layouts/application.html.erb  add

```
<head>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

and you can try only these line:

```
devise_for :users
```

instead of these lines

```
 devise_for :users do
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
 end
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything.. it redirects back to the index page, but remains logged in.. :(

Comment: did you put <%= csrf_meta_tag %> in your layouts/application.html.erb ?

Comment: Struggling with devise myself, so if I may ask: if you say: method:  'delete'  for your destroy path, shouldn't your route point to `devise/sessions#destroy` ? Or maybe the other way around: point your route to `devise/sessions#destroy` , then `method: destroy` instead of `method: delete` ? I can't try it myself right now, but I am curious.